# Assigning variable with return value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS, if you look at the following code, I would expect both x and y to be "hello"

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     NSString  *x,*y;

     y=    [x getstring];



}//viewDidLoad

-(NSString *)getstring{


    return @"hello";

}
```

Yet, I get this error: No visible @interface for NSString declares the selector 'getString'

I tried many things, I defined getstring in the .h file

Comment: You should explain why you expect that

Comment: Before explaining to @Wain question, please read more about `Objective-C`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your x variable is type on NSString ant there is no method getString defined there.

I believe you want to call `[self getstring]` instead:

```
y =  [self getstring];
```